# Do I need to check the CancellationToken in Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, cancellation-token

Here is the documentation for [How to: Cancel a Parallel.For or ForEach Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-parallel-for-or-foreach-loop)

And I've written a method to use that feature:

```
static async Task SpreadCheer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    var friends = await GetFriends();

    Parallel.ForEach(friends,
        new ParallelOptions
            { CancellationToken = cancellationToken},
        friend=>
        {
            SendCake(friend);
            // (*1)
        });
}
```

In the example in the documentation, on the last line of each loop, `(*1)`. It adds a `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

This confuses me, because then why did I pass it into the parallel options. I can also [see that](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,233) `Parallel.ForEach` will already throw after processing an item if the token is cancelled. It also throws immediately before starting any loops if the token is cancellation from the start. It is also my experience of running and testing this code that no explicit throw on cancelled is required.

**Do I need to (should I even) place a `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in position `(*1)`?**

Sure the documentation has an example of it, but it doesn't explicitly mention it, and if there was a unit test covering this, it's not code needed to pass that test. As far as I can tell.

---

Extra context:

Some context on cancelling. The reason for cancellation is that I have an Azure WebJob to SpreadCheer, Spreading Cheer can take a while, and I'd like to gracefully stop spreading cheer if Azure sends me a shutdown signal. I don't want to mess up anyone's cake.

Comment: In the meantime I've decided to not put anything in position (*1) on the basis that there is no test I could write that would go from red to green based on adding that code.

Comment: Coming back to this a few years later, I can see that the documentation was changed to remove (*1), more or less for the reasons discussed here https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/27457

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you should use `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` within the operations itself is, that the parallel operations will continue to execute until the very end.

`Parallel.ForEach` only checks the token at the beginning and at the end of the operation, not inbetween.

So if you have a lot of parallel operations, or long running operations, you will want to check for cancellation within the operation yourself.

You can verify the behavior with the following snippet, with or without the `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var source = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var token = source.Token;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 100), new ParallelOptions {CancellationToken = token},
                i =>
                {
                    for (var y = 0; y < 100; y++)
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{i} {y}");
                    }
                });
        }, token);

        Console.WriteLine("press return to cancel...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        source.Cancel();

        Console.WriteLine("press return to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you can add addition checks during your parallel operations in case there are natural stopping points at that more granular level. The check in the documentation is entirely unnecessary (and misleading), but just hints at the fact that it can be done in an example that would actually merit it, such as yours. I think that must be it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no reason to place a `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` as the last line in the `body` delegate. Adding this line at this place serves no purpose. The `Parallel.ForEach` checks on each iteration a flag that is updated in the [`CancellationToken.Register(callback)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register) delegate. This flag is updated practically at the same time with the flag stored inside the associated `CancellationTokenSource` itself ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cc89f381050ed576f8ca4e527d087b26e7ec6b23/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs#L954)), so you won't make the cancellation more responsive by adding this line.

That said, the [`ThrowIfCancellationRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested) method is extremely lightweight. It just checks the value of an internal `volatile` field ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cc89f381050ed576f8ca4e527d087b26e7ec6b23/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs#L69)). So although redundant, it won't have any noticeable effect on the performance of the parallel operation either.

A note about PLINQ. The [`WithCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withcancellation) operator in PLINQ checks the supplied `CancellationToken` [once every 64 iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880074/plinq-forall-withcancellation-is-not-working/74885040#74885040), so in this case a final `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is not redundant. It makes the cancellation more responsive indeed.