# PLINQ ForAll WithCancellation is not working

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, cancellation, plinq

I wrote a PLINQ query that ends with the [`ForAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.forall) operator, and I used the [`WithCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.withcancellation) operator in order to cancel the query midway. Surprisingly the query is not canceled. Here is a minimal demonstration of this behavior:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
cts.Token.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("--Token Canceled"));
    
try
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
        .AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(2)
        .WithCancellation(cts.Token)
        .ForAll(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing item #{x}");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            //cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        });
    Console.WriteLine($"The query was completed successfully");
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The query was canceled");
}
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mFrciu).

Output (undesirable):

```
Processing item #1
Processing item #2
Processing item #4
Processing item #3
Processing item #5
Processing item #6
Processing item #8
Processing item #7
Processing item #10
Processing item #9
--Token Canceled
Processing item #11
Processing item #12
Processing item #13
Processing item #14
Processing item #15
Processing item #16
Processing item #17
Processing item #19
Processing item #20
Processing item #18
The query was canceled
```

The query completes with an `OperationCanceledException`, but not before processing all 20 items. The desirable behavior emerges when I uncomment the `cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` line.

Output (desirable):

```
Processing item #2
Processing item #1
Processing item #3
Processing item #4
Processing item #5
Processing item #6
Processing item #7
Processing item #8
Processing item #9
Processing item #10
--Token Canceled
The query was canceled
```

Am I doing something wrong, or this is the by-design behavior of the `ForAll`+`WithCancellation` combination? Or it's a bug in the PLINQ library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be by design, but the logic is a bit different than you might expect. If we dig into source code a bit, we'll find related piece of `ForAll` implementation [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq.Parallel/System/Linq/Parallel/QueryOperators/Unary/ForAllOperator.cs,149):

```
while (_source.MoveNext(ref element, ref keyUnused))
{
    if ((i++ & CancellationState.POLL_INTERVAL) == 0)
        _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    _elementAction(element);         
}
```

So it *does* check for cancellation but not every iteration. If we check `CancellationState.POLL_INTERVAL`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Poll frequency (number of loops per cancellation check) for situations where per-1-loop testing is too high an overhead.
/// </summary>
internal const int POLL_INTERVAL = 63;  //must be of the form (2^n)-1.

// The two main situations requiring POLL_INTERVAL are:
//    1. inner loops of sorting/merging operations
//    2. tight loops that perform very little work per MoveNext call.
// Testing has shown both situations have similar requirements and can share the same constant for polling interval.
//
// Because the poll checks are per-N loops, if there are delays in user code, they may affect cancellation timeliness.
// Guidance is that all user-delegates should perform cancellation checks at least every 1ms.
//
// Inner loop code should poll once per n loop, typically via:
// if ((i++ & CancellationState.POLL_INTERVAL) == 0)
//     _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
// (Note, this only behaves as expected if FREQ is of the form (2^n)-1
```

So basically PLINQ developers assume that you have a very fast code inside `ForAll` (and similar methods), and as such they consider it wasteful to check for cancellation every iteration, so they check every 64 iterations. If you have long running code - you can check for cancellation yourself. I guess they had to do it like this because they can't do right thing for all situations in this case, however IF they checked every iteration - you would not be able to avoid the perfomance cost.

If you increase number of iterations in your code and adjust cancellation timeout - you'll see that indeed it will cancel after about 64 iterations (on each partition, so 128 total).

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft's engineers assumed that the PLINQ `ForAll` action is very fast, and the `Parallel.ForEach` is not. The `Parallel.ForEach` reacts promptly to the cancellation of the token, so I assume that the token is checked for each item, or at least more frequently than the PLINQ. [Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmdiFD).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, hard to say but I'd speculate that, since `Parallel.ForEach` was written first with the expectation of being applied to existing code bases, it was likely to be applied top down. The PLINQ comes a little later, more likely to be used for new code and learning some lessons from what came before. This is all conjecture and not based on verified facts.

Comment: @Jodrell I was also under the impression that the PLINQ is newer, but apparently both the `Parallel` and the PLINQ were introduced with .NET Framework 4.0 (2010). Links: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions?view=netframework-4.0#applies-to), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelquery-1?view=netframework-4.0#applies-to).

Answer (score 0):

[Evk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74885040/11178549) explains thoroughly the observed behavior: the PLINQ operators check the cancellation token periodically, and not for each processed item. I searched for a way to alter this behavior, and I think that I found one. When the parallel query is enumerated with a `foreach` loop, the cancellation token is checked on each iteration. So here is the solution that I came up with:

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes in parallel the specified action for each element in the source,
/// checking the associated CancellationToken before invoking the action.
/// </summary>
public static void ForAll2<TSource>(this ParallelQuery<TSource> source,
    Action<TSource> action)
{
    foreach (var _ in source.Select(item => { action(item); return 0; })) { }
}
```

The [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.select) operator projects the `ParallelQuery<TSource>` to a `ParallelQuery<int>` with zero values, which is then enumerated with an empty `foreach` loop. The `action` is invoked in parallel as a side-effect of the enumeration.

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LTiaEn).